# Need Verification on whether the following tool exists and a referral to the tool if it exists:

Tags: adobe, scanning, reformatting

I need to place one image from one report into a defined position on another report. For example: Reports 1,2, and 3 are physical pieces of paper that have a physical sketch in the top left corner. My boss likes his reports formatted a different way, hence, the sketch needs to be placed in the bottom right of the corresponding reports. Essentially, I could scan or take a picture of my report but need a mechanism to place the sketch from my report into a different position of the reformatted report. There are many of these reports so copy and pasting isn't time-feasible. A simple reference to a tool would really help me here.

I hope I am defining the problem correctly. I do not have any coding experience.

My effort was me searching for tools in Adobe Acrobat to make this work. I scanned all of my reports into adobe but could not find anything in the platform that could scan the sketch from my report and insert it into the reformatted report.